# JqGrid : Label value comes from database

Tags: jqgrid

I am a newbie to jqgrid, the challenge what I have now is label value.

My Jqgrid header structure look like the following :

> StoreName | StoreTag | 12SaleTotal | 01SaleTarget | alert

what I wanna do is that I need to get a month from a table from a database then put it on the label. For example, the current month is January, so SaleTotal will be set to previous month which is 12, and SaleTarget will be the current month which is 01.

Could you tell me how to achieve this ?
Is any formatter that I can use to customize the label?

Here is the code

```
function confirm() {
//get month from controller
  var settings = {
    url: '${contextPath}/resource-transfer/transfer/getMonth.do',
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        var a = data[0].value;
        var current = a.slice(-2);
        var previousMonth = parseInt(current) - 1;

        var workerAqRevAdjust = previousMonth + "SaleResult";
        var storeWorkerTargetAdjust = current + "SalePersonTarget";
        var storeTargetAdjust = current + "SaleStoreTarget";
        //$("#confirmTable").jqGrid("setLabel", "SaleResult", workerAqRevAdjust);
        $("#confirmTable").jqGrid("setLabel", "SalePersonTarget", storeWorkerTargetAdjust);
        $("#confirmTable").jqGrid("setLabel", "SaleStoreTarget", storeTargetAdjust);
        //clear jqgrid data
        $("#confirmTable").jqGrid("clearGridData");
        $('#confirmTable').jqGrid('setGridParam', {
            url: '${contextPath}/resource-transfer/transfer/confirm.do',
            datatype: 'json'
        }).trigger('reloadGrid');
        $('#confirmModal').modal('show')
    }
};
$.formAjax(settings);
```

}

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setLabel` method for example to change the column header dynamically. For example,

```lang-js
$("#gridId").jqGrid("setLabel", "SaleTotal", "12 Sale Total");
```

will set the string `"12 Sale Total"` as the column header of the column `"SaleTotal"`. By the way, you can use any HTML fragment as the value of label. For example, `"<b>12</b> Sale Total"` instead of `"12 Sale Total"`.

Comment: thank you Oleg, but I wanna change it once the jqgrid opened.  When data is loading (from controller), the jqgrid is already opened... but I can only get the month data once it's got return from the controller. Any suggestion?

Comment: @bill: You are welcome! I don't understand where you see a problem probably because you don't posted any code and don't explained what you do in details. How you load the data in the grid? When and wie get you the information about the labels, which you need to change? You can change the labels directly after you get the information. You can create the grid only at the moment. Alternatively you can create the grid inside of hidden div and show it only after all the required data are loaded. I can continue... There are exist a lot of options, but I have no idea what you want/need to implement.

Comment: I tried the updated code above, but the jqgrid does not change the label, could you help me on this?

Comment: $("#confirmTable").jqGrid("setLabel", 2, "abcdef")    ----->it works for me.. but using index is the good way to use?

Comment: @bill: `setLabel` should work with column names in the same way like with column indexes. In any way, in case of any problems you should *always* include **the version** of jqGrid, which you use, in the text of your question and **the fork**, which you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). The current version of free jqGrid fork, which I develop, is 4.15.2 and commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS is 5.3.0